# css infinite animation with linear characteristics

Tags: jquery, html, css

does some one have an idea of how the upper menu that is moving is done in the following page
http://www.tis.tv/

I have tried animation-transform but it once the animation is over the div comes back, and its nothing similar to the one on the page.

```
.footer div{
    -webkit-animation-name: prop-600;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 20s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

I have being searching for hours and i have no clue thank you,

Comment: Probably JavaScript

Comment: sorry im really new in this programming stuff, could you tell me what is a marquee

Comment: Sorry, no, it would not. Anything that moves on a page has to either stop after a set amount of time, or the user must be able to pause it. It must also be step-able, so the user can get at the content without hunting after an animation.

If not, you're violating accessibility standards that are codified into law in many countries and the stragglers are following.

Answer (score 2):

The site you linked is doing it with JavaScript, changing the left value. **But you can achieve it with CSS**.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vdoewz04/)

You need to display the same content several times. If the content doesn't occupy the screen width probably more than two times. Transform translateX the container an amount of percentage equivalent to 100/number of spans.

```css
body {
  overflow-x:hidden;//add overflow hidden on body to hide the horizontal scroll bar
}

.container {
  animation-name: somename;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  float: left;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

@keyframes somename {
  0% {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translateX(-33.33%);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
  <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DavidDylan. It might be a bad UX practice, and it is good to point it out, if the implementation is done as in the site linked. But we don't know the exact case the OP wants the technical solution for, nor the context.

Comment: Some things are bad practice in any context. Un-pausable, un-stepable animations are bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

It uses, what appears to be, a custom javascript ticker fxxx.tis.js. Which is hooked up to fxxx.tis.css for styling.

You can use a lightweight js scroller like 
http://www.codicode.com/art/jquery_endless_div_scroll.aspx
or 
http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Comment: If you inspect the source, you see the css left position is continually adjusted. Not what I would call a resource friendly solution, but apparently it works.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we could just use marquee and add a script to pause on mouse over. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/cegaqbqc/):

```
$(".myscroller").hover(function () { 
    this.stop();
}, function () {
    this.start();
});
```

Comment: Here is the same using without marquee tag. [edited fiddle by Alvaro]
https://jsfiddle.net/rawatdeepesh/vdoewz04/1/

Answer (score -1):

To avoid JavaScript, you could use a marquee. I know it's not great but it works.

This will move the text as you want. Scroll.

```css
marquee {
  background: yellow;
  padding: 10px;
}
a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<marquee>
  <a href="#">link</a>
  <a href="#">link</a>
</marquee>
```

Comment: I know that but I thought it's the only option not using JavaScript? Is there a better way?

Comment: The better way IS to use javascript, that's what it's there for. ;-)

Comment: Yeah suppose you're right. I didn't want to use marquee obviously we all hate them for a reason.

Comment: @DavidDylan No it is not better to do this with javascript. CSS is the way to do this. You have plenty of ways doing this with only CSS.

Comment: Please provide a way to comply with WCAG 2.0 using only CSS.